# phpmyadmin not working, browser shows a blankpage

Tags: 13.04, phpmyadmin

I would like to access `phpmyadmin`. I have access it before but, now, I'm just getting a blank page and I really don't know why.

How to set permission for `/var/www/phpmyadmin`? Is it necessary for working ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want set the user access then

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www/phpmyadmin/
```

will be fine.

about 755

- 7- user: He can do Read,Write,Execute
- 5- Group Uers: read & execute( cant modify)
- 5: other : Read & execute ( cant modify)

Answer (score 0):

I had a silly problem with phpmyadmin cause i came from Windows and didn't know you had to press SPACE when picking Apache2 when installing phpMyAdmin from the Terminal, it might not be the problem you're having but i think it's worth mentioning in case anyone else has the same problem.

When phpmyadmin asks you what web server you want to configure it for go to Apache2 press SPACE then TAB to get to OK and then press ENTER 
I was just pressing enter so it never configured phpmyadmin to run with Apache2